# Summing objects property in array

Tags: php

I have an array of objects, and i want to sum value of one of the properties, example:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => jon
        [commission] => 5

    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => smith
        [commission] => 1

    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => philip
        [commission] => 8

    )
)
```

I want to sum all the commissions in the array, result should be 14.

What is a good way for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($arrObj as $key=>$value){
  if(isset($value->commission))
     $sum += $value->commission;
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: What happens if some of the objects in the array do not contain commission or the commission equals null?

Answer (score 45):

`array_reduce` could be one way to do it; Just simply add your `$array`

```
$sum = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item)
{
    return $carry + $item->commission;
});

var_dump($sum);
```

Comment: is it necessary to use `+=` operator in the callback? I guess it can be just `+`?

Answer (score 24):

If you are using PHP 5.5

```
$arr_new = array_sum(array_column($yourarray, 'commission'));
```

Comment: The OP has an object, not array.

Comment: True, but this will work in a similar fashion if the object properties are public.

Answer (score 9):

Let's say $arr stores your information. Implement the following function:

```
function sumProperties(array $arr, $property) {

    $sum = 0;

    foreach($arr as $object) {
        $sum += isset($object->{$property}) ? $object->{$property} : 0;
    }

    return $sum;
}
```

After that you just have to call `sumProperties($array, 'commission')`.

Furthermore if you have more properties that could be summed, you could replace commission with those properties.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution IMO is to use `reduce`:

```
$total = array_reduce( commissionsArray, function ($sum, $entry) {
  $sum += $entry->commission;
  return $sum;
}, 0);
```

You can check it out here:
https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b4nG

However, if your array contains **arrays instead of objects**, you can use a readable code (it works for objects if your php versions is prior to 8.0.0, but it is not a very good practice to use implicit cast):

```
array_sum(array_column($commissionsArray, 'importe_final'));
```

You can chack it out here:
https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b4nK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but you can use this code (min version: PHP 7.4):

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(fn($item)=>$item->commission, $arrayOfObjects));
//commission is a property of your object which has one of the number types
```

In this example, we map array of objects to array of numbers, and then we can calculate sum of the array with `array_sum`.