# Php execute code only if result meets condition

Tags: php, foreach

I have a shop checkout function something like this:

```
    $min_delivery = 25;
    foreach ($shoppingCartItem as $item) {
     $insert->name = $item->name;
     $insert->price = $item->price;
     $insert->quantity = $item->qty;
     $insert->save();
     $total += $item->price*$item->qty;
    }
```

Is there any php function that would allow the foreach loop to happen only `if ($total > $min_delivery)` .

Or the only way would be to do the `foreach` twice, once only to calculate `$total`, then `if ($total > $min_delivery)` do a second `foreach` to insert into the database.

*EDIT - some details on why I want some other way instead of two loops:

The issue is that I can't trust the `$item->price` from the shopping cart because it comes from the user (and I don't verify it until checkout) so I need to check it against database before inserting.

So doing the loop twice would mean to query the database twice.

Comment: You answered your own question - first count total, then checkout.

Comment: @u_mulder That is one way yes, I asked if is there another way better?

Comment: You could use `array_reduce` to find the `$total`

Comment: Given that `$total` is calculated **in** the loop, I'm not sure that only executing the loop based on its value is going to get you very far. If there's a class involved that wraps the whole cart, adding a `getTotal()` method to it would make this a lot easier, and avoid the need to have a second dedicated loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194259/summing-objects-property-in-array is the right one, sorry copied the wrong duplicate $arr_new = array_sum(array_column($yourarray, 'commission'));

Comment: Another method, would be to generate the total during add/remove, and keep it in the cart as a separate variable to directly look at when you need. But it creates variable maintenance during add/remove cart items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution

```
$total = array_reduce($shoppingCartItem,
    function($carry,$item) {
        return $carry + $item->price*$item->qty;
    }
);
$min_delivery = 25;
if ($total > $min_delivery) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added some details in the main question on why I am looking for a solution without two loops.

Comment: This is only one loop :). But if you don't trust `$item->price`, I think you should fix that in the `$shoppingCartItem` object *before* doing this calculation.

Comment: I tried to avoid doing a query every time a item is added to the cart. This way I only query the database once on the checkout.